# Serverblock being ignored in Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

so I am trying to host multiple websites on a single server with nginx. I have a config set up, and the DNS records all work, and some of the things work, but one of the domains doesn't.

```
server {
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;


        root /var/www/aphrim.dev/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name aphrim.dev www.aphrim.dev; # managed by Certbot


        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }


    #listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/aphrim.dev/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/aphrim.dev/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}
server {
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;


        #root /var/projects/aphrim.dev/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name projects.aphrim.dev; # managed by Certbot


        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }


    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/projects.aphrim.dev/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/projects.aphrim.dev/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    listen 80; 
    listen [::]:80;

 #   root /var/projects/aphrim.dev/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name techchan.org;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

So, I am trying to get the 3rd server block to work, instead it just displays the content of the 1st server block. I know the content of the 3rd server block works because I put it onto the 2nd server block and it works.
If anyone has a solution I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of searching, found the issue. If anyone ever has the same question, just add

```
listen [::]:443 ssl;
listen 443 ssl;
```

and it should be fixed, at least that is what fixed it for me.